# GMaps4Rails MarkerCluster anchorText

Tags: google-maps, gmaps4rails, markerclusterer

I have a special marker cluster where the text is not properly aligned.

I have tried everything to move the text position:

```
 Gmaps.map.customClusterer = function () {

    return [
        {
            textSize: 10,
            textColor: '#000',
            url: '<%= asset_path 'grey-dot-2.png' %>',
            height: 38,
            width: 38,
            raw: 'anchorText: [5,0]',
            anchorText: [5,0],
            opt_anchorText: [5,0]
        }
    ];
};
```

But the text is always rendered in the same place. Any idea?

Comment: no clue, you'd rather change the tag, it's not related to gmaps4rails but to google clusterer

Comment: apneadiving: Did not fully understand your comment. You say that I'm doing it correctly and if it does not work the problem is with the Google Clusterer? I also did not understand why changing the tag would help.

Comment: I say I'm unable to solve google clusterer's questions. Changing tag would help your question get the visibility where it could be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try    anchor: [5, 0]

I was having a similar issue and I think it was just a different markerCluster version being used.

Comment: I was using the incorrect documentation. The gmaps4rails version I'm using uses http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/docs/reference.html

Comment: MarkerClusterPlus docs [link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) talks about anchorText to position text but the code uses anchor tag (like in simple MarkerCluster) ! Don't how to contact them to change the docs ...